# Convert managed C++ DLL project to unmanaged C++

Tags: python, c++, .net, dll, managed-c++

I got VS2008 project written in managed C++ that produces a utility DLL.
CLR Support: **Common Language Runtime Support, Old Syntax (/clr:oldSyntax)**

The resulting DLL exports a bunch of functions and complex types based on managed types like System::String, System::Byte and so on.

The DLL must be consumed (linked to) by a Python application. It seems that Python cannot use managed types/classes/structs.

Is it possible to convert the project so that it produces an "unmanaged" interface. That is, instead of working with System::String, I should somehow convert the types to std::string so that the Python app can work with?

The only "good news" is that the Python app that tries to consume the DLL needs to access only ONE exported function.

**Additional question**: if I only change the signature of that very function so that all the types of in/out parameters are unmanaged C++ would that work? The other exported functions will still work through managed types, but they won't be called at all.

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: [Using managed code in an unmanaged application - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10020/Using-managed-code-in-an-unmanaged-application)